# Verilog 4 bit multiplier?

Tags: verilog

I'm having problems on how to create a test module for the following Verilog code:

```
module Multiplier_4bit(output [8:0] y, input [3:0] i1, input [3:0] i2);
assign y=i1*i2;
endmodule
```

I thought of the following test module:

```
module M4_Tester
reg [3:0] i1;
reg [3:0] i2;
wire [9:0] y;
initial begin
i1=5;
i2=3;
$finish();
Multiplier_4bit device1(
  .out(y),
  .in0(i1),
  .in1(i2)
);  

endmodule
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong and sorry for bad english, as I am not a native speaker.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot instantiate a module inside of a begin block (put the multiplier somewhere outside of your `initial begin` block.
2. You have no corresponding `end` which closes the `initial begin` block.
3. Your simulation will terminate instantly because there is no delay between setting the values and the `$finish`. Put some nominal time delay before the simulation finishes with `#10 $finish()`.

Next time please clarify your question before asking, and post the actual error messages you are receiving.